# Are there any concepts that Da Vinci drew in his notebooks that still have not been realized today?

Tags: technology, renaissance, history-of-ideas

I know that da Vinci had a sketch of a perpetual motion wheel and a perpetual water pump but is there anything else he conceived of that modern science (mid-late 2023) has not achieved yet?

Comment: I do think that Leonardo da Vinci gets a lot of credit for things he didn't really invent. He was undoubtably a very imaginative, intelligent man but he wasn't into finishing things. He didn't actually end up with many finished (i.e. fully engineered) designs.

Comment: I do not think this question can be answered as written. Take for example the Great Kite - we have many flying machines, but none that work in this fashion (by the flapping of wings). Does this count as "being realized" or can it be dismissed as a flawed invention? And if it can, what is to stop us from dismissing the rest as similarly unworkable?

Comment: I’m thinking more of things like the perpetual motion wheel and the Organ viagro thing.

Comment: http://www.violaorganista.com/en/about/history/  Sławomir Zubrzycki built the Viola Organista between 2009 and 2012 based on  Leonardo da Vinci’s drawings and Michael Praetorius’s description. https://editions.covecollective.org/chronologies/only-modern-viola-organista-constructed

Comment: Oh cool! So I guess all that’s left that was never built was the Perpetual motion wheel as it is completely impossible and da Vinci even said that later on?

Comment: [Da Vinci's robotic knight](http://rosfilmfestival.com/en/a-robot-over-five-centuries-old-leonardos-mechanical-knight/) was only built in 2002.  Building fluidly-moving humanoid robots is still technically challenging today.